# How did the Avengers travel?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame* we see that the Avengers travel

> back in time to get the Infinity Stones.

But how did they get to where they wanted to be?

Like all of them were together before going back

> in time

at the Avengers facility.

How did Captain America, Iron Man, Ant-Man, and Hulk get to just a few meters from the

> Avengers Assemble in New York from *The Avengers*?

Comment: Fully functional time travel **GPS**? :)

Answer (score 10):

Presumably the quantum tunnelling time travel watch-like device they are all wearing that helps them navigate time also helps them navigate space. As we see them all leave the same location and arrive in different places and this is the device they use to get where they need to it makes sense that this is the case.

Comment: that is a good point i thought of it too, but if thats the case then why did war machine and nebula needed a spaceship to get the power stone in morag

Comment: @KevinKurien: they didn't. Widow and Hawkeye needed a space ship to get the Soul Stone on Vormir. Your question about why they couldn't go direct to the planet still stands, I don't think that's dealt with.

Comment: @KevinKurien That question has been asked as a new question now: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/212007/58193