# Why did these Avengers travel together?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

[This other post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/211948/why-did-they-wait-for-quill-to-arrive) alludes to my question, but doesn't ask it directly. In *Avengers: Endgame*, Nebula, War Machine, Hawkeye, and Black Widow all

> traveled back in time together to the planet Morag, where the Power Stone was located, and then Hawkeye and Black Widow took a ship to Vormir to get the Soul Stone.

My question is, **why did they travel together?** Couldn't they just have

> time traveled directly to Vormir, rather than take the ship?

Comment: Or travelled directly to the top of the mountain on Vormir? Why does no-one do that?

Comment: Vormir was the only location that none of the Avengers had ever been to.  Is it possible that they didn't have good enough spacetime coordinates to travel there directly?

Comment: @NathanK. That was my only guess - that you could only travel back to someplace close to your own timeline (unless you were accompanying someone). Nebula was in the vicinity of Morag, Thor was at Asgard, and the rest were in NYC. That wouldn't exactly explain how Cap and Tony went back further though.

Comment: It could be a holdover from prior plans, originally all four were going to Morag because Morag's land is underwater except for a specific time every few hundred years, and all four members would be needed to navigate the underwater expedition. However, that was eventually pared back, but perhaps them all arriving together was a remnant of that original script.

Comment: Avengers who travel together, stay together. Except that they didn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They were all going to the same time (2014), so the quantum tunnel was set to deposit them on Morag, from where Nat and Clint would use the shrunken Benatar ship to fly to Vormir.  I expect that they chose Morag because they knew when Quill would be there and that allowed them to target a specific time period, but the actual point at which they got to Vormir was less relevant as Thanos wasn't going to be getting the Soul Stone in 2014.

It's not stated outright in the film, but I got the impression that if you were travelling to a particular time, you all went to the same place rather than splitting off to multiple locations within the same targeted time period.  If this is the case, Nat and Clint could arguably have waited till the others had gone and then gone directly to Vormir via the Quantum Tunnel.  However, this is not definitive.

Comment: Whilst a nice theory this doesn't make much sense, they followed their space time quantum tunnel GPS to leave Earth and 2023 to get to Morag and 2014 so they could have easily split off and gone to Vormir as well.

Comment: As per the second paragraph of my answer, it **could** be a limitation of the quantum tunnel to only be able to get to a single location in a time period during a jump - which would mean that Nat and Clint would need to wait and jump later to retarget Vormir rather than Morag...  All a bit speculative though I know.

Comment: Oh I like the answer and it's probably what the directors/writers were going for but in universe it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Can't really disagree with that in terms of making sense :)

Comment: I kinda assumed that it is just easier to travel outside of the quantum realm. So do the hard part of traveling in time then travel in space once you get to 2014.

Comment: FWIW when Tony shows Cap the watch device when he arrives at HQ he calls it a _"A fully functioning Time-Space GPS"_ which means they should have been able to go to both locations together.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot It does not follow that "fully functioning" also means "without limitations".